# Appropriate way to search only using attributes and no full-text fields?

Tags: sphinx

Let's say I have a table structure like this:

```
name | groupId | locationId
```

And I use SphinxQL's realtime indexing features to index the records in the table, with `name` being `full_text` and `groupId` and `locationId` being `rt_attr_uint`.

I understand I can use SphinxQL to do a full-text search and use the attributes to filter results. So, for example, I could search for users that have the letters `Bo` in their name (e.g. Bob) and then filter results to only include records with `groupId = 1` and `locationId = 67`.

However, my question is whether using SphinxQL is still appropriate if I only want to use the attributes to filter records and am not doing full-text searching, or if I should revert to just doing a MySQL query for that? For example, if I wanted to retrieve all records with `groupId = 1` and `locationId = 67`, regardless of `name`.

I am asking instead of running performance tests myself because I've never used realtime indexing with Sphinx and am still trying to figure it out (actually, I'm still undecided on whether to use it..), so I really *can't* do tests myself at this time.

Or, going a completely different directly, should I just make `groupId` and `locationId` fields instead of attributes so that they are indexed?

Comment: Frankly I think you can only answer this with testing. Sphinx have very different performance curve than MySQL (being of course designed very differently) - some queries will work much better on sphinx, some with will better on mysql

Comment: btw, you can use disk indexes for 'quick and dirty' testing. They allow you to to create new sphinx indexes very quickly, with different settings. You can then use these indexes for running tests on **query** performance. Only switching later to using proper RT indexes - when go live.